# experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator& operator++()

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm writing a program that takes all the file names in a directory and puts them in an array. The problem i'm having is the operator++() shows an error and won't increment the iterator. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Select a directory :";
    std::string path;
    std::cin >> path;
    std::cout << "How many files :";
    int dirFiles;
    std::cin >> dirFiles;
    int i = { 0 };
    std::vector<std::string> fileNames(dirFiles);

    for (auto& p : fs::directory_iterator(path)){
        while (i < dirFiles) {
            fileNames[i] = p.path().string();
            fs::directory_iterator& operator++();
            std::cout << fileNames[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This hasn't to do with C++17.  C++17 includes filesystem in the standard library; you appear to be asking about an earlier TS.

Comment: I get an error without #include <experimental/filesystem> and it won't even read the first file name, this way at least reads the names. I can also output all files to console.

Comment: In C++17 you need `#include <filesystem>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) already knows how to loop over its constituent elements. You do not need to do additional work yourself:

```
std::vector<std::string> fileNames;

for (auto& p : fs::directory_iterator(path)){
    fileNames.push_back(p.path().string());
}
```

Comment: worth to link [explanation how range-based "for" loop works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) here